# XHR HTTPRequest with Hashed form data?

Tags: python, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, python-requests, screen-scraping

So as I was trying to scrape using xhr and requests in python, I came across form data that seems to be encrypted. Has anyone come across this before and how did you overcome scraping the form data?

[image: What the form data I'm trying to pull from looks like.]

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: please provide the link so people can analyze your particular case.

Comment: what did you do to get that data? I mean, the process.

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. I was using the chrome dev tools to find the correct links and areas to scrape the data. I went to the website, entered the flight form data on their booking page, and hit the search button. However, this I've never seen before, where the form data is seemingly encrypted so that we can't see the IDs to pull. How do I get around this?

Comment: @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. Thoughts?